# Text overlaid with Ghostscript not visible

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I am using the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885483/can-i-use-ghostscript-to-overlay-a-text-fax-header-onto-a-pdf-and-or-tiff) to overlay text onto a PDF.

It works - partially: the text is there (I can copy it and it shows using pdftotext) but is not visible - there's probably lots of stuff on top of it.

How do I ensure it's on top, or at least visible?

Comment: Add the text **after** running the input file (that is run the PostScript in -c/-f after the PDF file), or (much better) use an /EndPage procedure to write the text, so that it gets done as the last thing before the page is emitted. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243044/is-it-possible-in-ghostscript-to-add-watermark-to-every-page-in-pdf/12596669#12596669